# Media queries transition issues

Tags: html, css, media, transition, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have 3 different media queries in my website and when I pass from one to another, by reducing the browser window, the transition is not fluid. The page changes layout for a few moments and then it continues to the next media query. I can't figure that problem out and I am using Skeleton so it should be all smooth.

This is the website, try no shrink the page and you will see that before passing to the tablet or mobile layout it acts strange.
http://www.andrearizzotto.com

Answer (score 0):

Change your `media queries` ranges to `993px-801px` and `800px-480px`

Comment: thank you mate, nothing changes tough, still the same problem

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: As i did not had any code i did these changes in dev tool of chrome and it worked for me. Try and adjust the values of queries and it should solve the issue. What i found out was that page does not change the layout for few moments as stated in the question but at a 2 particular widths, which i then included in the `media queries` and it solved the issue for me.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try to change browser, at the moment I am using Safari.

Comment: Even safari has a dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

The columns are supposed to be organized in individual rows with the total number of columns for the fluid layout to work properly.

There are a total of sixteen columns in the stylesheet, which means the each row should have sixteen colums or less to behave like we want them to.

Example

this:

```
<div class="ten columns" id="head">
  <h1><a href="../index.html">ANDREA RIZZOTTO</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="six columns" id="head2">
  <h3><a href="CONTACT/contact.html">CONTACT</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="ABOUT-ME/about-me.html">ABOUT ME</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="index.html">WORK</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="eight columns" id="body">
  <a class="on2" href="the-green-room/the-green-room.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/greenroom.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <p class="text"><a class="on" href="the-green-room/the-green-room.html">The Green Room</a></p>
</div>

<div class="eight columns">
  <a class="on2" href="evanescent-catalog-design/evanescent-catalog-design.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/evanescentcatalogdesign.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <p class="text"><a class="on" href="evanescent-catalog-design/evanescent-catalog-design.html">Evanescent Catalog Design</a></p>
</div>

<div class="eight columns">
  <a class="on2" href="evanescent-identity/evanescent-identity.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/evanescent-identity.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <p class="text"><a class="on" href="evanescent-identity/evanescent-identity.html">Evanescent Identity</a></p>
</div>

<div class="eight columns">
  <a class="on2" href="moa-identity/moa-identity.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/MOAidentity.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <p class="text"><a class="on" href="moa-identity/moa-identity.html">Museum of Associations Identity</a></p>
</div>
```

Should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="ten columns" id="head">
    <h1><a href="../index.html">ANDREA RIZZOTTO</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="head2">
    <h3><a href="CONTACT/contact.html">CONTACT</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="ABOUT-ME/about-me.html">ABOUT ME</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="index.html">WORK</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="eight columns" id="body">
    <a class="on2" href="the-green-room/the-green-room.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/greenroom.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p class="text"><a class="on" href="the-green-room/the-green-room.html">The Green Room</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="eight columns">
    <a class="on2" href="evanescent-catalog-design/evanescent-catalog-design.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/evanescentcatalogdesign.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p class="text"><a class="on" href="evanescent-catalog-design/evanescent-catalog-design.html">Evanescent Catalog Design</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="eight columns">
    <a class="on2" href="evanescent-identity/evanescent-identity.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/evanescent-identity.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p class="text"><a class="on" href="evanescent-identity/evanescent-identity.html">Evanescent Identity</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="eight columns">
    <a class="on2" href="moa-identity/moa-identity.html"><img class="imageborder" src="images/MOAidentity.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p class="text"><a class="on" href="moa-identity/moa-identity.html">Museum of Associations Identity</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```